# How can I add the RestContext.response in the batch class finish method?

Tags: batch, apexrest

I am creating a REST class wherein all the processing is done by a batch class. I would want the RestContext.response line to be made after the execute method. But it returns this error: "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object". This error occurs even if I put the line of code in the execute method.

Is it possible to put the RestContext.response in a batch class? Or is there any better way to do it? Hope you can help me...

This is my code:

```
global class sample_API {
@HttpPost
  global static void getAccounts() {
    
    sampleAPIBatch runAPIBatch = new sampleAPIBatch();
    Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(runAPIBatch);
  }
}
```

/*batch class*/

```
global class sampleAPIBatch implements Database.Batchable <sObject>, Database.Stateful, Database.AllowsCallouts {
...

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> scope) {
    ...
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {  
    //here results to : System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object  
    RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(theResult));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following (assuming `theResult` is a stateful batch class variable)

```
RestContext.response resp = new RestResponse();
resp.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(theResult));
```

*Note it is a bit weird for the `finish()` to construct a `RestResponse` but presumably you are passing this to some other method that is expecting this.*